# Adding UILabel in center of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

My UICollectionView creates some custom UIViews (called NumberViews)

each NumberView has an attribute `var text: UILabel!` which is a label and should be spawned in the middle of the NumberView.

What I do is:

1. I create the NumberViews inside the UIViewController
2. I create the labels inside the NumberViews

(1) works just fine, but (2) don't. It creates the label in some strange place outside the NumberView.

For (2), I do this in the init of NumberView:

```
var text: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.text = UILabel(frame: frame)
    self.text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.text.text = "testing"
    self.addSubview(self.text)
}
```

and what happens is something like this:

```
               ______________    _
              |              |    \
              |     ______   |    |
 NumberView --|--> |      |  |    |
              |    |______|  |    |
              |              |    |
      Label --|----> testing |     > ViewController
              |              |    |
              |              |    |
              |              |    |
              |              |    |
              |______________|   _/
```

How can I move the label to the middle of the NumberView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add layout anchors to your numberView setting it's center.x and center.y to be equal to the label's.

I'm not at my Mac right now but you should be able to search for code to create center layout anchors.

A quick search turned up this site:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/

You want to create a centerXAnchor And a centerYAnchor

Comment: maybe this website is not what you intended to send